# Installing EC2 .pem publickey to Debian ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, public-key

I recently generated a publickey (`.pem`) from an EC2 instance, used `ssh-add` to add the key to my local machine. The IdentifyFile in the Host entry at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` points to the .pem file at `~/.ssh`.  As noted in the AWS guide, I used `chmod` to edit permissions on the file before invoking `ssh-add`.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting:

```
user@deb $ ssh aws
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I don't think it's relevant, but for the record it's the 5th or 6th key I've generated for the EC2 instance. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa on your local computer then you should be able to use the command ssh-copy-id  to install the key on the remote computer.

```
ssh-copy-id
Usage: /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id [-h|-?|-f|-n] [-i [identity_file]] [-p port] [[-o <ssh -o options>] ...] [user@]hostname
        -f: force mode -- copy keys without trying to check if they are already installed
        -n: dry run    -- no keys are actually copied
        -h|-?: print this help
```